# plot data of time interval type in R

Tags: r, postgresql

these data are exported from `postgresql` of `interval` type, for example:

```
1 00:01:30
2 00:07:00
3 00:07:00
4 00:03:00
5 00:02:00
6 00:03:30
7 -00:02:00
...
```

#### what i want

I want to see the distribution of these data, and what's more, I want to get the decile of the distribution, even if it's interval time.

#### what I did

1. I used the :

   ```
   COPY (SELECT the_interval from the_table) TO '/some/file/path.txt';
   ```

   to get the file `path.txt`.
2. then I used

   ```
   tools -> import datasets -> from loalfile
   ```

   to get the data imported into workset of `R` with `RStudio`.

#### what I am asking

I'm new to `R`, and I want to know: do I need to transfer the data into `time` type in R, or any function I could use to plot these data. Or any further, you can propose me any better way you think that it would achieve the goal I expressed.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can read your data into R as character strings.  The easiest option is to convert your times into interval objects with the "times" function.  From there R makes it easy to plot a histogram.

```
#Sample data
t<-c("00:01:30", "00:07:00", "00:07:00", "00:03:00", "00:02:00", "00:03:30", "00:06:00")
#load library and convert to a times object
library(chron)
tt<-times(t)

#Plot the histogram
h<-hist(as.numeric(tt), main="sample data", col="blue")

#For data summaries
summary(tt)  
quantile(tt, 0.90)
```

Hope this provides you a head start on solving your problem, if not please ask a more detail question providing some sample data and the expect output.

Comment: Thanks, and I tried, but you might not notice that I have some negative data, which is `interval` type in `postgresql`. but, I think I could transform them into time and then plot them. anyway, thanks for your answer, it did help.